# Can someone point out what am I doing wrong jquery - moving list item

Tags: jquery, listbox, append

list item is not moving from one list box to another . I tried to debug script with firefox but it never goes inside the button.click . I am not sure what am I doing wrong . Thanks for your help.

I have a master page :
then I have a content page where I added:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/UiEffect/dragdrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my html in content page HTML: List box item I am getting from DB using Databind()

```
<div class="question">

       <asp:ListBox ID="Allitem" runat="server" Rows="7" Width="200px" ></asp:ListBox>

        <input id="ibtnLeft" type="image"  src="../Images/LeftArrow.png" />
        <input id="ibtnRight" type="image" src="../Images/rightArrow.png" />
       <asp:ListBox ID="selectedItem" runat="server" Rows="7" Width="200px"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
```

and here is my j-query for dragdrop.js external file:

```
$("#ibtnRight").click(function ($e) {
    $("select[id$='Allitem'] option:selected").appendTo($("select[id$='selectedItem']"));
    $("select[id$='Allitem'] option:selected").remove(); $e.preventDefault();
});

$("#ibtnLeft").click(function ($e) {
    $("select[id$='selectedItem'] option:selected").appendTo($("select[id$='Allitem']"));
    $("select[id$='selectedItem'] option:selected").remove(); $e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: jQuery function `appendTo` **moves** the element inside DOM, so the `remove` function is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I am able to see in firebug and I was able to call alert.

Comment: It would be more beneficial to show the rendered markup than your server-side template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in 'dragdrop.js' needs to run after the DOM has loaded, or the selectors may miss their targets that haven't yet been created.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // run initializing code here
});
```

Also as @Chris has pointed out, the id's may not render as you think they are.  In that case, you can use inline dynamic javascript on the page itself in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%= Allitem.ClientID %>').doSomething();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that ASP.NET changes IDs sometimes when you actually run the code, are you sure the IDs your targeting via JQuery are the same ones defined in your code. and as a side note why not move ASP.NET MVC.